# Leave some columns while copying to new DataFrame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to remove some columns of a DataFrame in R and copy the rest into a new DataFrame. Since the number of columns i have to copy is more, and the number of columns that I need not to copy is just three, I don't want to write individual colnames for copying.

Here is what I wrote -

```
col = c("ta_rating_score","id","city_id","image_quality_score")
imp_col = data[,~col]
```

I got this error-

```
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'language'
```

Not able to get where I am going wrong.

Comment: `data[,~col]` is not correct R syntax. Negative indexes are used like `data[,-col]` but these have to be numeric indexes. I suggest you use something like `?setdiff` as in `data[,setdiff(names(data),col)]`

Comment: @thelatemail Thanks.. It worked. :) Understood the error as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setdiff` and `names` to select columns by exclusion.

Without recreating your data...

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:8, y = 11:18, z = 21:28)

print(df[,setdiff(names(df),'y')])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try with

```
data[, -which(colnames(data) %in% col)]
```

For example you can see with `mtcars` dataset

```
mtcars
#                    mpg   cyl  disp  hp  drat   wt  qsec   vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           21.0   6   160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6   160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          22.8   4   108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6   258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8   360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             18.1   6   225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#Duster 360          14.3   8   360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#Merc 240D           24.4   4   146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230            22.8   4   140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Merc 280            19.2   6   167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#Merc 280C           17.8   6   167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#Merc 450SE          16.4   8   275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL          17.3   8   275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC         15.2   8   275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8   472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#Lincoln Continental 10.4   8   460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8   440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#Fiat 128            32.4   4   78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47   1  1    4    1
#Honda Civic         30.4   4   75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52   1  1    4    2
#Toyota Corolla      33.9   4   71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90   1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corona       21.5   4   120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Dodge Challenger    15.5   8   318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#AMC Javelin         15.2   8   304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#Camaro Z28          13.3   8   350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8   400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#Fiat X1-9           27.3   4   79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90   1  1    4    1
#Porsche 914-2       26.0   4   120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#Lotus Europa        30.4   4   95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90   1  1    5    2
#Ford Pantera L      15.8   8   351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#Ferrari Dino        19.7   6   145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#Maserati Bora       15.0   8   301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#Volvo 142E          21.4   4   121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

cols <- c("mpg", "cyl")
mtcars[, -which(colnames(mtcars) %in% cols)]

#                    disp  hp drat    wt  qsec  vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4           160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag       160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710          108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive      258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout   360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant             225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
#Duster 360          360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
#Merc 240D           146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230            140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Merc 280            167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
#Merc 280C           167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
#Merc 450SE          275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SL          275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
#Merc 450SLC         275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
#Cadillac Fleetwood  472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
#Lincoln Continental 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
#Chrysler Imperial   440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
#Fiat 128             78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#Honda Civic          75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#Toyota Corolla       71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
#Toyota Corona       120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
#Dodge Challenger    318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
#AMC Javelin         304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
#Camaro Z28          350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
#Pontiac Firebird    400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
#Fiat X1-9            79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
#Porsche 914-2       120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
#Lotus Europa         95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
#Ford Pantera L      351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
#Ferrari Dino        145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
#Maserati Bora       301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
#Volvo 142E          121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

PS: I have used variable name as `cols` here as `col` is a base R function, so it is advised not use a variable with a function name. See `?col`

Comment: You don't even need `which`, since you can use logical indexing: `data[, !colnames(data) %in% col]`